# Which table in Dynamics NAV contains Salesperson code?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I want to connect to Dynamics Nav through SQL.

Which table in Dynamics NAV contains 'Salesperson code'? It can be viewed in Aging of Receivables report? What are the keys to join between [CompanyName$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] and [CompanyName$Cust_ Ledger Entry]?

Does any table contain information on actual 'Salesperson code' (not the former when receivable was created)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is "Cust Ledg entry no" on detailed-table.

Is table "Salesperson_Purchaser" what you are looking?

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that there is [Salesperson Code] in [$Cust_ Ledger Entry] table. Is it the actual code? I mean if the responsible sales person changes, how can I match the receivable to new person?

Comment: What do you mean by "changes"? Customer Ledger Entry holds posted records. Posted means that the sale is completed. What is the point of changing salesperson after sale is completed? You cant do this. So you cant trace it.

Comment: Sales YES, it is completed but receivable for that sale may NOT be completed. The  customer may not pay at once and the sales person may not work that long to see the payment. The person responsible for collecting the payment may be different - though it is rather a charge person, not sales person.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin, you need to update your question or ask a new one.

Adjust the editability on the posted pages. This isn't usually recommended though. If you have a dimension linked to Salesperson, you'll need a routine to update the transactions.